# MNIST dataset on Spyder

Tags: one-to-many

I need to install mnist dataset to Spyder (not part of Anaconda), but get the answer that
keras is not found. The Python on Spyder is 3.9.14. How can I do it?

I need to install mnist dataset to Spyder (not part of Anaconda), but get the answer that
keras is not found. The Python on Spyder is 3.9.14. How can I do it?

import sqlite3
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
from builtins import dict
from keras.datasets import mnist
(train_X, train_y), (test_X, test_y) = mnist.load_data()

answer:
runfile('/Users/nevendragojlovic/Desktop/Software/eyeye35.5.py', wdir='/Users/nevendragojlovic/Desktop/Software')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File ~/Desktop/Software/eyeye35.5.py:14
from keras.datasets import mnist

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

Comment: Just to clarify, libraries are not installed *into* Spyder. They are installed into the core Python environment, or virtual environment.  Is `keras` installed?